WebMvcTest Spring Boot 3.2.4 and httpservletrequest
I have this exception in a thymeleaf template org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains('admin')" (template: "operations/fragments/navigation.html" - line 49, col 32)  . I think the httpServletRequest is null.
Should the httpservlet object be mocked by WebMvcTest annotation? The problem is that this request comes from this test:
@WebMvcTest(OperationsController.class)
public class OperationsControllerTest extends BaseWebTest {

..............
............ // removed lines for simplicity
@Test
public void testGetAdminPage() throws Exception {
    // given
    final var adminPage = "admin";
    final var responsePage = "operations/administration";

    // when & then
    this.mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_PATH + "/" + adminPage))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name(responsePage));
}

In previous version of Spring Boot I used (version 2 and java 11) there was no issue.
And this is the template part having the issue:
<a class="nav-link nav-link--header"
   th:href="@{operations/admin}"
   th:classappend="${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains('admin')} ? 'nav-link--active' : ''">
   <span class="text-underline">Administration</span>
</a>


What does your BaseWebTest look like, what lines did you remove? How did you setup MockMvc. Too little information to begin answering this.

I also think that the variable to use is request and not httpServletRequest in thymeleaf (at least by default).
